# pyrthon recursively create xml using lxml

Tags: python, recursion, lxml

I'm trying to create a function in python that would accept any sort(dictionary/arguments) and number of arguments to recursively build an xml tree. However I can't seem to figure out the logic. This is what I have so far:

```
from lxml import etree as e

def CreateSubNode(top, *args, **kwargs): 
    root = e.Element(top)
    for key, val in kwargs.items():
        if type(val) == dict:
            return CreateSubNode(key, **val)
        c = e.Element(key)
        c.text = str(val)
        root.append(c)
    return root

details = {'name':'someguy', 'age':'23'}
address = {'city':'sometown', 'state':'somestate'}

final = CreateSubNode(top = 'information', details=details, address=address)
text_buf = e.tostring(final, pretty_print=True)
print text_buf
```

And my output is:

```
<details>
  <age>23</age>
  <name>someguy</name>
</details>
```

It's not printing anything after the first argument, and its also not creating the parent node (in this case, information). Any help on what I'm doing wrong? I'm not too good at recursion...

Comment: wow I figured it out right after I posted this. I will post the answer I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to save the recursive result:

```
def CreateSubNode(top, *args, **kwargs):
    root = e.Element(top)
    for key, val in kwargs.items():
        if type(val) == dict:
            c = CreateSubNode(key, **val)
        else:
            c = e.Element(key)
            c.text = str(val)
        root.append(c)
    return root
```

Comment: haha thanks! I figured it out right after I posted, but I will select your answer as the right one as its the same as what I got :)

Comment: @still.Learning lol when I posted it there was no answer yet, but you won (by 8sec) xD

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out right after I posted the question:

```
def CreateSubNode(top, *args, **kwargs): 
    root = e.Element(top)
    for key, val in kwargs.items():
        if type(val) == dict:
            c = CreateSubNode(key, **val)
        else:
            c = e.Element(key)
            c.text = str(val)
        root.append(c)
    return root
```